# Discord.py on_member_join and on_member_leave not working

Tags: discord, discord.py

I started using `discord.py` (not `discord.ext` commands, only `import discord`). Recently, I made a channel, the name of which shows the member count in the guild, and it updates everytime someone joins or leaves. This is my code:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel('channel id here')
    await channel.edit(name = 'Member count: {}'.format(channel.guild.member_count()))
    
@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
    channel = client.get_channel('channel id here')
    await channel.edit(name = 'Member count: {}'.format(channel.guild.member_count()))

client.run('my token here')
```

I also added `client.on_message` command so the bot would edit that name to whatever I typed in.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message)
     if message.content == 'rename channel':
            channel = client.get_channel('channel id here')
            await channel.edit(name = 'TEST')
```

Now, after adding some print's for debugging, I found out that `on_member_join()` and `on_member_leave()` never get called, but the bot edits the channel's name when I type the command. That's a voice channel, which shows member count. There aren't any errors. Did I read the API wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but the reason behind your `on_member_join` and `on_member_leave` not working maybe because of intents not being passed.

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

and then you want to enable server intents in the bot application. I faced this issue when I made my bot as well.

Answer (score 7):

IDs of any kind in discord should be passed as an integer, not a string. Additionally, [`discord.Guild.member_count`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member_count#discord.Guild.member_count) is an attribute, not a method, so use it without the parentheses. You should also be using [`on_member_remove()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove) instead of `on_member_leave()`.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    await channel.edit(name = 'Member count: {}'.format(channel.guild.member_count))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    await channel.edit(name = 'Member count: {}'.format(channel.guild.member_count))

client.run('my token here')
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the on_member_remove() gets called but does not edit the channel name, and it does not finish (it doesnt reach the print line i added on the end)

Comment: `await channel.edit()` doesn't print anything, also make sure the channel ID you chose actually exists

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) in the discord developer portal, and then the code would be like such:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)

# etc.
```