# discord.py - Join/Leave messages error, doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Again, my code is not catching up, I have no idea why ...
The console shows no error.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(792786709350973454)
    author = ctx.message.author
    ico = author.avatar_url
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color = discord.Color.red(),
    )
    embed.set_author(name=(f'• Hello {member} on my server!!'))
    embed.add_field(name='Warning,', value='read the regulations!', inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="dBot created by Diablo#4700", icon_url=ico)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on\_member\_join and on\_member\_leave not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62123044/discord-py-on-member-join-and-on-member-leave-not-working)

Comment: I corrected and still the bot does not send messages to the given channel, errors are not there.

Comment: @DiabloStudio Does your bot have the permissions to send messages in that specific channel ( <#792786709350973454> )?

Comment: Has permissions, and you still can't see the message.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any errors? There's a comma at the end of the 7th line in that snippet that isn't followed by an argument, which should raise a syntaxerror. Also, have you passed the intents into your Bot/Client constructor?

Comment: Still not working and the console after the bot fleet is clean, showing no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more then one problems in the code snippet. I'll list them all here with fixes.

- Firstly the main problem, you are declaring an `author` variable with **`ctx.author.name`** What is `ctx` here? `ctx` is passed in commands only. This is an event. It uses `member` as parameter only you can't use `ctx` here.
- Secondly, the next problem which isn't really playing a part in stopping the command output but is a problem that you are sending `member` in your embed author message. Again `member` is an object and you can't use it directly you have to put the attribute after member that you need like, `member.name`, `member.mention`, `member.avatar_url`

**Fixed Code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(792786709350973454)
    # author = ctx.message.author # first problem, you don't really need this line 
    ico = member.avatar_url # since above line is useless you would change this line too
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color = discord.Color.red(),
    )
    embed.set_author(name=f'• Hello {member.name} on my server!!') # second problem was here.
    embed.add_field(name='Warning,', value='read the regulations!', inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="dBot created by Diablo#4700", icon_url=ico)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I have labelled the errors with comments.


**(IMPORTANT) Intents:**

Just in case you are not aware, You need privileged gateway intents in order to track member events. Make sure to enable both intents from bot section in your application from Developers Portal of Discord and then in your code at the top (where you are initializing bot)...

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client= commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix", intents=discord.Intents.all()) 

...
# rest of the code
```

**References:**

[`on_member_join` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join)
[`context` or `ctx`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context)
[Intents Discord.Py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)